# Error when inserting array value into database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am inserting multiple images into database but getting such error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '0, 1) VALUES (Array, Array)' at line 1
>
> INSERT INTO `CompleteProjectImage` (0, 1) VALUES (Array, Array)

I am holding list of selected image in the controller and passed it to my model.

Here is my model coding to insert into database.

```
public function create($projectDetails, $projectDescriptions, $projectImages){

    $this->db->trans_begin();


    $this->db->insert(self::$tblCompleteProject, $projectDetails);
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    foreach ($projectDescriptions as $projectDescription) {
        $insertDescription = array(
            'project_id'   => $insert_id,
            'description'  => $projectDescription,
        );
    }

    $this->db->insert(self::$tblCompleteProjectDescription, $insertDescription);

    foreach ($projectImages as $projectImage) {
        $insertImage[] = array(
            'project_id'   => $insert_id,
            'img_src'      => $projectImage['img_src'],
        );
    }

    $this->db->insert(self::$tblCompleteProjectImage, $insertImage);  // Error inserting to this database

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
        return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1) ? false : true;
    }

}
```

`print_array($insertImage);` resulting :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [project_id] => 5
            [img_src] => 594a7f9a79285.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [project_id] => 5
            [img_src] => 594a7f9a792851.jpg
        )

)
```

Comment: Well .. it looks like the query builder in that ancient framework does not support multiple row insert in a single query. Try looking up the source for the `insert()` method, or do the inserts in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not insert an array into database you should either turn it to a Json object or select indexes one by one.

insertImage is an array but your `Insert` func doesn't accept an array and directly insert the parameter in the query !

A turnaround for you:

```
foreach ($projectImages as $key => $projectImage) {
        $insertImage[$key] = array(
            'project_id'   => $insert_id,
            'img_src'      => $projectImage['img_src'],
        );

$this->db->insert(self::$tblCompleteProjectImage, $insertImage[$key]);
}
```

I am not sure this is what you want but according to the snippet this is the proper way of inserting